# Create pdf file with ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript, sco-unix

I'm using SCO Unix, with old version of ghostscript (7.7). When I convert the postscript source file to pdf otput file, It's content is visible on the SCO machine. But when I copy the pdf file into windows, and open it with adobe acrobat, all I can see is a blank page. Does anybody have a solution to this?

Comment: How do you copy the file?  With ftp?  If you use ftp, did you use binary mode to transfer the file?

Answer (score 0):

It may because you have not embedded the fonts in the PDF. Windows did not have the Unix fonts and that is why are seeing a blank page. To be sure, open the PDF in Adobe Reader and press Ctrl+D. Check the fonts tab and see if those fonts are available in Windows. You could try copying the Unix fonts to Windows Fonts folder. But the better approach would be embed the fonts into the PDF on the Unix terminal itself.